# Numpy strange behavior - sanity check. How is this possible?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm no Python expert by any stretch of the imagination, but this one has me stumped. Either that or I'm missing something completely obvious. It must be one of the two.

I have two numpy arrays, `a` and `b`. `a` should be a proper subset of `b`. To confirm this I produce the set difference:

```
>>> np.setdiff1d(a, b)
array([], dtype=float64)
```

as expected. `a` is therefore a subset of `b`.
Unless my understanding of `setdiff1d` is wrong, which I suppose it could be, but I reread the documentation and it states that `setdiff1d` returns a:

> Sorted 1D array of values in ar1 that are not in ar2.

Ok, here's where something strange happens. I have some value `p`. The following should be a true statement if `a` really is a subset of `b`:
***if `p` is in `a`, then `p` is also in `b`***

When attempting to confirm this, I get:

```
>>> p in a
True
>>> p in b
False
```

So I'm not sure exactly what's going on, and I was hoping someone would point at my stupid mistake and laugh.

Comment: You're comparing floating point numbers by determining if they are exactly equal to one another but they aren't due to floating point errors.

Comment: That's it. Thanks. Between moving between Pandas and Numpy the dtypes on the id columns diverged (probably due to type cohesion?), and one was float64 while the other was int64. If you copy your comment into a response, you've got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setdiff1d` and your other methods check number for *exact* equality. Due to floating point errors, it is very possible that your numbers aren't *exactly* equal. If you want to do floating point comparisons, you should instead use a very small epsilon.

```
if abs(a - b) < 1e-12:
    disp('equal!')
```

Comment: See also http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html and http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose for routines that do floating point comparison with tolerance for you.